# How do I get the signatures of all possible overloaded methods?

Tags: c#, reflection

I would like to get an array of objects containing all possible overloaded method signatures for a method in a class. For example if we have:

```
public class SomeClass {
    ...
    public void SomeMethod() { ... }
    public void SomeMethod(int i) { ... }
    public void SomeMethod(string s) { ... }
}
```

how can I find all possible parameter infos? I tried using:

```
MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod(methodName);
ParameterInfo[] possibleParameterInfos = method.GetParameters();
foreach (ParameterInfo possibleParameterInfo in possibleParameterInfos)
{
    Console.WriteLine(possibleParameterInfo.ParameterType);
}
```

but I am not getting what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [`GetMethods`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td205ybf(v=vs.110).aspx) not `GetMethod`

```
MethodInfo[] methods = type.GetMethods()
                           .Where(x => x.Name == "SomeMethod")
                           .ToArray();
```

Then you can call `GetParameters` on each `MethodInfo` to get the signature of each method.

```
foreach(var mi in methods)
{
    foreach(var p in mi.GetParameters())
    {
        Console.Write(p.ParameterType + ",");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```